# Persisting Botpress running on my server instance

Tags: bots, botpress

So I am able to setup Botpress bot engine to my Alibaba Cloud VPS instance but immediately I exit the terminal, the engine stops. Would anyone kindly help me know how to persist the instance after I exit the terminal.
I am using the pre-compiled binaries. I ran this on the terminal:
`./bp`

Answer (score 0):

To let the `bp` binary running after you leave the terminal, simply launch the command followed by an ampersand:

```
./bp &
```

This will instruct your shell to run Botpress in the background.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Closing the ssh window killed the process